# How to handle (or ignore) null properties in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

I have a Javascript object from a part of a Graph that on some rows may not have all data details

So when I put this on the HTML

```
{{ip.Out.StockItem[0].Out.Properties.Name}}
```

VueJS gives this error on console

> Unable to get property 'Name' of undefined or null reference"

and does not render the page when the `Properties` is null.

I tried

```
{{ip.Out.ItemEstoque[0].Out.Properties?.Nome}}
```

But then no error, and no page is rendered.

The data comes from a WebAPI and I can not enforce all objects will have all data filled in.

**How to solve this?**

Comment: The answers worked here, but it would be nice to have some way / option in VueJS to handle those null / missing properties more easily and seamlessy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ternary if statement.

Following code checks whether `ip.Out.StockItem[0].Out.Properties` exists and if true get the `Name`, else displays nothing.

```
{{ip.Out.StockItem[0].Out.Properties ? ip.Out.StockItem[0].Out.Properties.Name : ''}}
```

alternativelly you can also use a template

```
<template v-if="ip.Out.StockItem[0].Out.Properties">
    {{ip.Out.StockItem[0].Out.Properties.Name}}
</template>
<template v-else>
    -NO DATA-
</template>
```

Comment: This worked well here! I was using a template (more verbose). Thank you! Maybe VueJS could have a setting to ignore null properties / arrays by default.

Comment: @Tony According to the creator of Vue.js, it seems not going to happen. https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4638#issuecomment-270142138

Answer (score 2):

if any property can be null or undefined on any level in the object, the most error-free way is to

```
    {{
        ip &&
        ip.Out && 
        ip.Out.StockItem &&
        ip.Out.StockItem[0] &&
        ip.Out.StockItem[0].Out &&
        ip.Out.StockItem[0].Out.Properties &&
        ip.Out.StockItem[0].Out.Properties.Name
        ?
        ip.Out.StockItem[0].Out.Properties.Name
        :
        ""
    }}
```

but apparently this is too verbose. A library like https://github.com/erictrinh/safe-access could make your life easier

Comment: +1 Very good point! I am trying to return a Graph object from a Azure Functions WebAPI, and I can not guarantee all levels of the object to be filled.